# Getting demographics info about youtube channels using youtube api

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube, youtube-api

I need to access Youtube channel's demographics data with oauth.

One problem is that Youtube api called insight only provides zipped folders with csv files.

While I can probably download the zip, unzip, access the file, and delete the original once I get the data I need, I was wondering if there is any other way to get youtube channel's demographics data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that yes, using the new YouTube Analytics API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports

From the doc:

Channel reports

The table below lists the different types of channel reports accessible via the API. To retrieve a channel report, set the ids parameter value to channel==USER_ID, where USER_ID specifies the YouTube user ID of the currently authenticated user.

And I think that is the report you wants:

```
dimensions: country

metrics: views, comments, favoritesAdded, favoritesRemoved, likes, dislikes, shares, subscribersGained, subscribersLost

filters: video
```

or this one:

```
dimensions: ageGroup, gender

metrics: viewerPercentage

filters: country video(,country)
```

and this example shows how to call the API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application